# Python type annotation for a sorted list

Tags: python, python-typing

```py
def my_function(dist: list[int], clabels: list[int]):
    ...
```

What is the proper way to hint that the `dist` argument in `my_function` must be a sorted list of integers?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to express that in a type hint. You can make up a custom alias, like `SortedList = list[int]`, to express it informally…

Comment: There is no way to represent "sorted" within the type system. I don't know of any language that has that. That would be extremely difficult to verify. Just document that you expect a sorted list in the docstrings, and make it a module private function if you don't want it to be misused.

Comment: Type hints are for *types*. Being sorted isn't part of the type, it's a description of the value.

Comment: Also, regarding your `= []` default argument, you should give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) a read over if you haven't already. Be careful using mutable default arguments.

Comment: @Carcigenicate you could make a `SortedList` class that has a normal list as inner state that it re-sorts on each `append` and `expand` etc.